# How does Facebook implement the comet (long-polling) in the server side?

Tags: facebook, real-time, comet, long-polling

It seems Facebook implements the long poll technique to get the 'real' data. What implementation do they use in the server side? I thought they were using Tornado but they only use it for their FriendFeed service.

Anyone knows?

Thanks